# Asm syntax highlighting not working in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: assembly, visual-studio-2015, syntax-highlighting, masm

I've installed [AsmDude](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Henk-JanLebbink.AsmDude) through the Visual Studio marketplace. I restarted my computer and tried editing a .asm file, but the syntax highlighting is not showing.

[image: Text Editor]

I've gone to Tools -> Options -> AsmDude and it says that sytax highlighting is enabled.

[image: AsmDude settings]

I also can't get Visual Studio's built in MASM syntax highlighting to work by following the instructions on how to do that.

Why can't I get any syntax highlighting working?

Comment: The author [has a page where you can post bugs](https://github.com/HJLebbink/asm-dude/issues/37), it seems more suited that this site. Have you checked the basics? the plugin installed fine, it is active, the file extension is asm/cod/inc, and whatever things VS needs to work.

Comment: There is no built-in MASM syntax highlighting. It is otherwise impossible to diagnose what you are doing wrong. AsmDude works fine for me in VS 2015 with .asm files.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Goto Tools > Options > TextEditor > FileExtensions. You may have associated the extension .asm to an editor. If you have done that AsmDude can't take control over files with the .asm extension. For the same question (and answer) see [here](https://github.com/HJLebbink/asm-dude/issues/43).